# How to redirect to another page in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code for registration. Values are inserted properly but page is not redirected to another page:

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];//check whether form is submitted or not
    $email = filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);//email validation
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $profession = $_POST['profession'];

    check validation of email
    if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)){
        echo 'invalid email';
    }

    else

    {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registerpro WHERE email = '$email'");selecting email from database
        $data = mysql_num_rows($result);//check if there is result


        if($data==0){

            $qry = mysql_query("INSERT INTO registerpro (company_name,email,password,phone,city,profession) VALUES ('$company_name','$email','$password','$phone','$city','$profession')");
```

here i is the problem as page is not redirecting to another page so please tell me how to fix it

```
            if($qry){



                header("Location : company_info.php");//redirect to company_info

            }
            else`enter code here`
            {
                echo 'error';
            }
        }else{
            echo 'invalid email';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

After registration page is not redirecting to `company_info`.

Comment: Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions! use PDO / MySQLi instead. And your PHP script contains lots of syntax errors. SQL Injection may occur as well. Duplicate call of `filter_var()`. Didn't use `exit` after `header("Location: $url");`. TONS OF ERRORS !

Comment: yeah i know but this is my first assignment and just learning ... will cover everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove extra space after `Location`

So, change

```
header("Location : company_info.php");//redirect to company_info
```

To:

```
header("Location: company_info.php");//redirect to company_info
//              ^ here
```

Comment: wooo....its that simple....thanks a ton for help was frustrated so much....i am new to php so little mistakes are really difficult to notice....

Comment: In my answer, you might be seeing a 2 upvotes and up and down arrows. Below that there is a right (right sybmol) in white, you click on it and it will turn green.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out after struggling a bit. If you perform a web search on the PHP header() function you will find that it must be used at the very top of the file before any output is sent.

My first reaction was "well that doesn't help", but it does because when the submit button is clicked from the HTML input tag then the header() function will get run at the top.

To demonstrate this you can put a section of PHP code at the very top with the following line...

```
print_r($_POST);
```

When you then press the "Submit" button on your web page you will see the $_POST value change.

In my case I wanted a user to accept the Terms & Agreement before being redirected to another URL.

At the top of the file before the HTML tag I put the following code:

```
<?php
   $chkboxwarn = 0;
   /* Continue button was clicked */
   if(!empty($_POST['continue']) && $_POST['continue']=='Continue'){

      /* Agree button was checked */
      if(!empty($_POST['agree']) && $_POST['agree']=='yes'){
         header('Location: http://www.myurlhere.com');
      }
      /* Agree button wasn't checked */
      else{
     $chkboxwarn = 1;
      }

   }
?>
```

In the HTML body I put the following:

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="yes"  /> I understand and agree to the Terms above.<br/><br/>
   <input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue"/>
</form>

<?php
   If($chkboxwarn == 1){
      echo '<br/><span style="color:red;">To continue you must accept the terms by selecting the box then the button.</span>';
   }
?>
```